# Finding the percentage (%) range of average value in SQL

Tags: postgresql, t-sql

I am wanting to return the values that lie within 20% of the average value within the Duration column in my database.

I want to build on the code below but instead of returning Where Duration is less than the average value of duration I want to return all values which lay within 20% of the AVG(Duration) value.

```
Select * From table
Where Duration < (Select AVG(Duration) from table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
Select * From table
Where Duration between (Select AVG(Duration)*0.8 from table)
and (Select AVG(Duration)*1.2 from table)
```

perhaps this to avoid repeated scans:

```
with cte as ( Select AVG(Duration) as AvgDuration from table )
Select * From table
Where Duration between (Select AvgDuration*0.8 from cte)
and (Select AvgDuration*1.2 from cte)
```

or

```
Select table.* From table
cross join ( Select AVG(Duration) as AvgDuration from table ) cj
Where Duration between cj.AvgDuration*0.8 and cj.AvgDuration*1.2
```

or using a window function:

```
Select d.* 
from (
     SELECT table.*
        , AVG(Duration) OVER() as AvgDuration
     From table
     ) d
Where d.Duration between d.AvgDuration*0.8 and d.AvgDuration*1.2
```

The last one might be the most efficient method.